# How can I get in laravel Elequent Model?

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

Suppose I have a model called Payment with field(column) student_id,fund_id,amount ,class_id 
If data in the table are

```
student_id class_id    fund_id    amount
 1          1           1        100
 1          1           1        200
 1          1           2        150
 1          1           2        500
 2          1           2        100
 2          1           1        300
 2          1           2        300
 3          3           1        100
 4          2           2        100
```

I want to get result like

```
class_id     student_id     fund_id    amount
1              1              1           300
1              1              2           750
1              2              1           300
1              2              2           400
2              4              2           100
3              3              1           100
```

sorting will be class_id then student_id group by fund_id

what will be the query in laravel using elequent model?

Comment: What does your database even look like?

Comment: database table name payment  and column are student_id , fund_id, class_id, amount @Jerodev

Comment: To get started with figuring that out, how would you write out the SQL query, taking Eloquent out of the equation?

Comment: I have no idea with group by fund_id  @ChrisForrence . Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple order by on an eloquent query, than group by and sum:

```
$result = Payment::orderBy('class_id')
    ->orderBy('student_id')
    ->groupBy('fund_id')
    ->sum('amount')
    ->get();
```

Comment: but I need summation of fund_id amount also with ordering  @Apród Illés

Comment: it says "Call to a member function get() on string" @ApródIllés

Comment: @HelalUddin Remove the `get()`. `sum()` already does the get.